# Delete users profile and deploy your own Users Webpart for all users in the farm

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

[image]

Is it possible to Detele this Webpart in every users profile?Because i want to have my own Webpart Profile . And is there any way to do this for all users at only one Deploy , and not manually to every singel user, and also how do i Deploy a webpart to every users profil , so the users all have the same webpart , and that i dont need to deploy on every users profile.

Comment: Are you talking about the My Profile page? If so, these are just Sharepoint pages. You can edit them and remove web parts if you are an admin.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use your own profile page you should implement delegate control that redirects user to your page, this page you can put to the layout folder. If you look at userdisp.aspx page you can find declaration of delegate control.

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" id="DelctlProfileRedirection" ControlId="ProfileRedirection" Scope="Farm" />
```

Comment: i have tryed to create a new profile , but even if i create a own , the site looks the by default , just like it did before?

Comment: I don't understand what you did and what you would like to see. The base approach is to implement delegate control in the farm feature. This controls should only redirect the user to a page that you created and placed to the layout folder. When you clicks on user name, you are redirected to the userdisp.aspx. In this time you delegate control is called. It sees that it should redirect user to your page and do it. In this case you should have your page with default master page for my site host.

Comment: i dont understand , do u maybe have a guide that i could follow ? or something ?

Comment: see [this post](http://www.trinkit.com/blog/2007/10/15/how-to-customize-the-user-information-page-part-2)